# how to handle a DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions in discord.js when removing roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a bot that removes all roles from a user, however, when the bots role is below the role it is trying to remove. It obviously doesn't have permissions so it throws the error `DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions`, crashing my bot. How can i handle this to `message.reply(member + 'roles are too high for me to remove')` When this happens as i cant think of a way to code this in. Heres the function that removes the roles at the moment:

```
if (message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
            if (!args[0]) {message.reply('you need to ping someone to smac after =smacmedown')
            } else {
            let member = message.mentions.members.first();
            member.roles.remove(member.roles.cache);
            }
        } else { message.reply('only admins can use the smacmedown command!:sob::sob:') }
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: if anyone was going to say it, i just made a small modification to the code to make it a little better, moving the ```let member = message.mentions.members.first();``` to under the administrator if statement and changing ```if (!args[0])``` to ```if (!member)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.remove()` returns a promise (`Promise<GuildMember>`). It will resolve with the member if the action was successful and reject with the error object on any kind of error. Handle the promise.

By simply adding a `.catch()` callback, the promise is handled and therefor does not throw an `Unhandled promise rejection error`

**ALSO**: The best way to remove all roles of a member is to do `member.roles.set([]);`

```js
member.roles.set([])
   .then(member => /* On Success */)
   .catch(err => /* On Error */);
```

If you want to use Async/Await

```js
try {
   await member.roles.set([]);

   /* ... On Success */
} catch (err) {
   /* On Error */
}
```

Here's the Documentation for [GuildMemberRoleManager#remove()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=remove) and [GuildMemberRoleManager#set()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=set)